# Suggestion to concatenate (join) strings from dictinary values

Tags: python, dictionary

with the following snippet I can achieve what I'm looking for:

```
d = {}
d[1] = 'one'
d[2] = 'two'
d[3] = 'three'

exp = ''
for k, v in d.items():
    exp += '{}@1 + '.format(v)

exp = exp[:-3]

exp
'one@1 + two@1 + three@1'
```

I was wondering if there are some better solution than deleting the last characters.

Comment: `' + '.join('{}@1'.format(v) for v in d.values())`

Comment: `exp = ' + '.join([f'{v}@1' for v in d.values()])`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: `join` accepts a generator, so square brackets are not needed.

Comment: @Amadan I know, I even like the way it looks better, but for some reason the fact that it is inconsequentially faster to use the list comprehension compels me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`join`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm):

```
d = {}
d[1] = 'one'
d[2] = 'two'
d[3] = 'three'

exp = ' + '.join('{}@1'.format(v) for v in d.values())    
print(exp)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
one@1 + two@1 + three@1
```